# Error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mode'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv, image-enhancement

I have looked this error here but the code was different , he used  PIL.ImageOps

So basically I got an error with this code:

```
img1 = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\final project\Image processing\PC3\PC3_Glucose_1.tif', 0)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img1)
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img1)
enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(1.8)
# enhanced_im.save("enhanced.sample5.png")
img = cv2.resize(enhanced_im, (960, 540))
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The traceback is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yael/PycharmProjects/FinalProject/Cell_Detection.py", line 9, in <module>
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img1)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\ImageEnhance.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.degenerate = Image.new(image.mode, image.size, 0)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

I was trying to take a very dark image and make it brighter so i can see the image. when I was using MATLAB I used imadjust

```
image = imadjust(dark_image,[0 adjustment],[]);
```

So I'm trying to imitate that on Python

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please share a minimal, reproducible example?
please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.imread` returns a `numpy.ndarray` object, however `ImageEnhance.Brightness` is expecting a `PIL.Image.Image` object, as can be seen in the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageEnhance.html?highlight=ImageEnhance.Brightness#PIL.ImageEnhance.PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness).

Check the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#open-rotate-and-display-an-image-using-the-default-viewer) for creating a `PIL.Image.Image` object from a path.